# Python return regexp-formatted string

Tags: python, regex

There is an input string like "2r-rj1225-f11e-12-x-w"

The task is to return it in the following format:

- all groups except the first and last must be 5 characters
- the first and the last groups must be between 1 and 5 characters
- if the first group in the input is less than 5 characters, it must be preserved

that results to  is "2r-rj122-5f11e-12xw"

```
import re

string = "2r-rj1225-f11e-12-x-w"
baseLength = 5

def formatKey(string: str, baseLength: int) -> str:
    p = re.compile(r"{1,baseLength}[a-zA-Z0-9]{baseLength}[a-zA-z0-9]+")
    formatted = '-'.join(p.match(string))
    return formatted

print(f'The reformatted string is {formatKey(string, baseLength)}')
```

that does not work, naturally. And I also wish to avoid '-'.join and to simply return something like regexp(re.compile('[a-z]FORMATREGEXP'), string) where FORMATREGEXP is the regexp that does the job.

Clarification: The actual solution is to use re.sub(pattern, repl, string) function: *"The sub() function searches for the pattern in the string and replaces the matched strings with the replacement"* -- And that is exactly what I've been asking for, that simple, in one line!!

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: Also, "the first and the last ones can be shorter" leaves room for interpretation. If the first group is under 5 characters, must it be preserved (as the example does)? Could the first group instead be 5 characters, as is done with the following? Is it coder's choice?

Comment: f-string together with regex grouping means that you need to escape the brackets, `fr"{{1,{baseLength}}}[a-zA-Z0-9]{{{baseLength}}}[a-zA-z0-9]+"`

Comment: I think it is more a combinatorics problem. Is regex a must?

Comment: @outis {1,5}-{5}-{5}-{5}-{1,5} characters separated by '-'. That must be the output of regexp formatting. The last group can be less than 5 chars. And the first group preserves its char number if that was less than 5.

Comment: @cards regex is the preferable and should be the mist simple one-line method. But other methods of doing that can be used too.

Comment: @CodeGust: thanks, that clarifies the problem. Note that clarifications should be [edit]ed into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), rather than being left as [comments](/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Where is the task coming from?

Comment: Actually, I am surprised to see the reaction and low competence here. The actual solution is  to use `re.sub(pattern, repl, string)` function: "The sub() function searches for the pattern in the string and replaces the matched strings with the replacement"  And that is exactly what I've been asking for, that simple!!

Comment: @CodeGust: careful about insulting those you're going to for help. Generally, the reason askers don't get answers that resolve their problems is that they haven't described the problem well enough, or even asked the right question. Given that the result groups will generally span the separator, which regexes won't deal with easily, I suspect that is the case here. Note you can answer your own question.

Comment: And, again, where is this task coming from? What is it for? Who assigned it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see this as a regex problem.  It's just reorganizing the characters after the first hyphen.

```
x = "2r-rj1225-f11e-12-x-w"

def reencode(x):
    parts = x.split('-')
    p1 = ''.join(parts[1:])
    s = parts[0]
    while len(p1) >= 5:
        s += '-' + p1[:5]
        p1 = p1[5:]
    if p1:
        s += '-' + p1
    return s
print(reencode(x))
```

Output:

```
2r-rj122-5f11e-12xw
```

Comment: thank you. that is an ok solution but specifically regex one would be greatly appreciated.